# Saving forms in Django in case of many-to-many

Tags: python, django, save

I have read through all discussions related to this topic, but still cannot figure out what's the problem.

```
 tempTaskForm = newTaskForm.save(commit=False)
 tempTaskForm.children_are_visible = True
 responsiblePeopleFormTemp = responsiblePeopleForm.save(commit=False)
 tempTaskForm.parent_id = parentId
 tempTaskForm.children_number = 0
 responsiblePeopleFormTemp.task =  newTaskForm.save()
 responsiblePeopleForm.save() # Error raised
```

Model:

```
class Tasks(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    description_short = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    description_full = models.TextField()
    status = models.ForeignKey(TaskStatus, default = 1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    type = models.ForeignKey(TaskType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_start = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    date_end = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    is_important = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    parent_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    rgt = models.IntegerField()
    lft = models.IntegerField()
    parents_number = models.IntegerField()
    children_number = models.IntegerField()
    children_are_visible = models.IntegerField()  # This field type is a guess.
    visible = models.IntegerField() 

    effective_from = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    effective_to = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'tasks'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return smart_unicode(self.id)

class TaskResponsiblePeople(models.Model):
    task = models.ForeignKey('Tasks', models.DO_NOTHING)
    auth_user = models.ForeignKey(User, models.DO_NOTHING)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'task_responsible_people'
```

Forms

```
class TaskResponsiblePeopleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TaskResponsiblePeopleForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field_name, field in self.fields.items():
            field.error_messages={'required':  'Придется не поленится и заполнить это поле...'}
            field.widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
            field.required = True

class Meta:
    model=TaskResponsiblePeople
    fields = ('auth_user',)

class TaskForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TaskForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    self.fields['description_short'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control input-sm'})
    self.fields['description_full'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control'})
    self.fields['date_start'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control'})
    self.fields['type'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control'})

    self.fields['date_end'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control '})
    self.fields['is_important'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control'})

    self.fields['description_short'].required = True
    self.fields['description_full'].required = True
    self.fields['date_start'].required = True
    self.fields['date_end'].required = True    
    self.fields['is_important'].required = False

    for field_name, field in self.fields.items():
        if field.required == True: 
            field.error_messages={'required':  'Придется не поленится и заполнить это поле...'}

class Meta:
    model=Tasks
    fields = '__all__'
    exclude=['id','parent_id,', 'rgt', 'lft', 'parent_id', 'visible','children_are_visible','parents_number', 'children_number', 'effective_from', 'effective_to', 'status']
```

I get `ValueError: save() prohibited to prevent data loss due to unsaved related object 'task'`. I spent hours trying various variants, but no success. Any ideas should very appreciated

**Edit: Model added**

Comment: Does the Model behind `responsiblePeopleForm` have a `ForeignKey` relation to the Model behind `tempTaskForm`?

Comment: I have added the model. See the edited question

Comment: You should also post the forms. How are you setting the value for the id field?

Comment: Added the forms as well

Answer (score 0):

Your `TaskResponsiblePeople` has a non-nullable `ForeignKey` to `Tasks`. Thus, if you want to save an instance of `TaskResponsiblePeople` which is implicitly done by the form's `save` method, you have to make sure that the related `Tasks` instance is saved (in order to have a primary key). 
Removing the `commit=False` from your first line should do the trick, since that flag prevents the model instance from being saved when you call save on the form.

Comment: Commit=false is needed to be able to assign value to parent_id, children_number, etc

Comment: Then you have to save it after assigning those values. Insert `tempTaskForm.save()` before the line that throws the error.

Comment: Note that the variable name `tempTaskForm` is not helpful because the save method of a `ModelForm` does not return a form instance, but an instance of the underlying `Model`.

Comment: I can't assign values before saving. The fields subject to value assignment are sort of technical fields and they are excluded from the form. That's why I have to use commit=false